# How to format , set min , set max date attributes in servicenow date picker?

Tags: angularjs, servicenow-client-scripts

Im currently designing the widget in servicenow widget editor where I wanted to use date picker. How to format the date, set min , set max date attributes in servicenow date picker?. The below HTML elements sets the date as "MM-DD-YYYY" when I select the date. I wanted to format it as "YYYY-MM-DD" and also, wanted to set the min and max date ranges?